# leaving out some implicit parameters

Tags: scala, implicit, named-parameters

Is it possible to leave out some implicit parameters but not all of them? I tried with named parameters:

```
def foo(implicit a: Int, b: String) {
  if (a > 0) {
    println(b)
    foo(a = a-1)   // error
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler rejects the recursive call of `foo` with:

```
not enough arguments for method foo
Unspecified value parameter b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to leave out some implicit parameters. So, in your example

```
def foo(implicit a: Int, b: String): Unit = ???
```

It is not possible to only specify `a`. However, you can specify the default value of the implicit parameter, for example

```
def foo(implicit a: Int, b: String = "---"): Unit = ???
```

Where if `b` is not implicitly available, `"---"` will be used.

Remember that the `implicit` keyword marks the *parameter list* as implicit, not that *one parameter* as implicit.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but something like this could do:

```
def foo(implicit a: Int, b: String): Unit = {
  def helper(a: Int)(implicit b: String): Unit =
    if (a > 0) {
      println(b)
      helper(a - 1)
    }
  helper(a)
}
```

Comment: Clever! With over 60k rep between you, you make me feel clever, too, like listening to Mozart.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge In fact, your clever currying made me want to try something, too, and I seriously thank you. You may object that my solution isn't terribly clever, but does Mozart complain that all those babies listening to his music turn out dumb?